# Java: printf is not applicable for the arguments (String, double)

Tags: java, io, compiler-errors, printf

I'm trying to compile code that I know to be working on other peoples' machines but is throwing a particular error on my system. Specifically the error relates to the printf() method

> The method printf(String, Object[]) in the type PrintStream is not
>   applicable for the arguments (String, double)

For instance

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        double rate =10.5;
        System.out.printf("%.3f",  rate);
    }
```

Does anyone know why this error is cropping up? There are alternatives to using printf(), but this is very annoying!

Comment: Try wrapping it in `new Object[] {rate}`.

Comment: I don't get the same error with that code. I suspect that something else is wrong.

Comment: What Java version are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it possible that you hav Java compiler compliance level 1.4?

Comment: Is this an answer to OP's problem, or rather a comment? I guess it's probably the second.

Comment: I should rephrase that: The only explanation I can think of is that the OP has its Java compliance level set to 1.4. I think it is very probable that this is causing the observed error.

Comment: @EelLee: I think that this answer is closer to the mark than yours. 1+ up-vote. I don't see anywhere in the code example or the error message where autoboxing applies. I do see however where printf didn't exist in Java 1.4.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I don't think this meets any standard of answering (as I'm reading different questions, I notice that experienced users put such a questions in the comments), yet I think it's worth to ask the author which Java version he's using (which I have just did). Thanks.

Comment: To make clear: the question is not which Java version you are using, but which Java Compiler compliance Level, see e.g. the Eclipse documentation on this setting: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Fjava%2Fref-preferences-compiler.htm

Comment: Yes, thanks: editing the Java Compliance Level (to 1.6) under Properties in Eclipse sorted the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The funny thing is that it compiles without problem on Java 7, and prints out

> 10.500

It probably uses `autoboxing`. But omitting the issue of autoboxing - as your method accepts only `Objects`, and not `primitives`, you need to use a wrapper `Double`.